# sql join int varchar

Tags: sql, int, inner-join, varchar

I've been searching the questions but haven´t found an answer. I would like to do an inner join with Table 1 and Table 2 , but one field is INT and other is VARCHAR (with the structure "A-INT"). Something like:

```
    Table1                    Table2

    ID NAME   WHATEVER        ID USER
    1  A-001  ---             1  001 
    2  A-002  ---             2  002
    3  A-003  ---             3  003
    3  A-004  ---             4  004  
    ...
```

How can I construct the query? Something like:

```
... Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.NAME = Table2.[A-USER] ...
```

Comment: which dbms ? for these operations, functions are often different from one to another...

Comment: Is it the `ID` or the `USER` field from `Table2` that you want to use in the join?

Answer (score 9):

You would need to convert the `int` value to `varchar` and concatentate it with `'A-'`, or get the numeric part of the `varchar` value and convert to `int`.

This is done a bit differently depending on what database you are using, for SQL Server it would look like this:

```
select t1.ID, t1.WHATEVER, t2.USER
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.ID = cast(substring(t1.NAME, 3, 3) as int)
```

Comment: Just in case somebody finds this question useful, in this case it would be substring(t1.NAME,3,3)

Answer (score 0):

Try by concatenation,

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b
WHERE a.Name = 'A-' + b.User
```

but take note, this decreases the performance.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus the question illustrates the `USER` has `000` format.

Comment: Yes, that's why i deleted, sorry ;)

Comment: in MYSQL this only works if b.User is a string. If you need to concatenate (and cast types) use `concat('A-', b.User)`

Answer (score -3):

You want to do inner join on  Table1.NAME = Table2.[A-USER].

If Table1.NAME, Table2.[A-USER] column datatype is different means, its not possible to use inner join.